# Gulp.js error on gulp.watch "Arguments to path.resolve must be strings"

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to move my file path globs into an object at the top of my gulpfile. After refactoring my gulpfile like this I started to get this error trigged by `gulp.watch`:

```
throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.resolve must be strings');
```

At the top of my gulpfile I've defined a variable `srcFolder` which should be the name of the folder that contains the source files for my project. Then I create a map containing the paths that are associated with each task and append this folder name to the beginning of each path. In this example my `srcFolder` is just called "src", and I am only seeing this error when I have an "src" directory to watch. For example, changing `srcFolder` to "foo" or changing `gulp.watch` to look at "foo" will not cause an error.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/alextebbs/51cd9355da157407fcc7) is a link to my gulpfile stripped down to a single task (styles). Line 70 is where I call `gulp.watch`. My gulp version is 3.6.2.

Answer (score 14):

It's simply poor api design. You need to pass the task list as an array, even if it is a single task.

```
gulp.watch(srcGlobs.style, ['styles']);
```

should work.